# Directory.GetFiles does not return files copied from a computer (Android MAUI)

Tags: c#, android, maui

I'm developing an app in VS MAUI which is supposed to handle files and subfolders in the Download folder (external card) on an Android. The phones File Manager app reports 3 files in the folder, but my app lists only 1.

```
           var f1 = Directory.GetFiles("/storage/8186-1418/Download");
```

The listed file has been created by the app itself, using File.WriteAllText, so I know I have access to the folder. The 2 files that aren't listed have been copied from a computer over USB to this folder, so I'm suspecting I'm missing some permissions.

The following permissions have been specified in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_USB" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

What do I need to do to see all files?

Comment: As I remember you cannot access files your app does not own directly this way. You need to use special mechanisms provided by Android (Storage Access Framework).

Comment: Well that is for Android 11+ devices only.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the manage_external_storage permission in your file so you need to use the ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION intent action to direct users to a system settings page where they can enable the following option for your app: Allow access to manage all files.

Firstly, use following code to judge current version and pop a in method of .SnackbarOnCreateMainActivity

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 
        Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.R)
        {
            if (!Environment.IsExternalStorageManager)
            {
                Snackbar.Make(FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content), 
                "Permission needed!", Snackbar.LengthIndefinite)
                .SetAction("Settings", new 
                ClickHandler(this)).Show();
            }
        }
}
```

Then you can achieve the ( execute ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION intent action to direct users to a system settings page) to grand the permission.MyClickHandlerManage_External_Storage

```
internal class ClickHandler:Java.Lang.Object ,View.IOnClickListener
{
    private MainActivity mainActivity;
    public ClickHandler()
    {
    }
    public ClickHandler(MainActivity mainActivity)
    {
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }
    public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        try
        {
           
          Uri uri = Uri.Parse("package:" + 
          Application.Context.ApplicationInfo.PackageName);
          Intent intent = new    
          Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.
          ActionManageAppAllFilesAccessPermission, 
          uri);
            mainActivity.StartActivity(intent);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.SetAction         
    (Android.Provider.Settings.ActionManageAppAllFilesAccessPermission);
            mainActivity.StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```